# Why does my regular expression pattern for the Leetcode problem 193. Valid Phone Numbers not work?

Tags: bash, shell

Problem Link: https://leetcode.com/problems/valid-phone-numbers/

The bash script:

```bash
grep -o -w -e "([0-9][0-9][0-9]) [0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]" -o -w -e "[0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]" file.txt
```

fails on the last test case.

However,

```
grep -o -w -e "^([0-9][0-9][0-9]) [0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]$" -o -w -e "^[0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]$" file.txt
```

passes all the testcases.

The only difference between the two being `^` and `$` which specifies that the start of the line should follow the pattern and that the end of the line should also follow the pattern.

Why should we specify that only 1 phone number is there in each line?
Could you provide a simple testcase which fails for the 1st bash script but passes for the 2nd bash script.

Comment: Trivially, it matches too much; it will falsely claim that 1234-456-789-00007 is a match.

Comment: For future reference you can use `{N}` to repeat the previous item exactly `N` times. So `[0-9]{4}` is equivalent to `[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]`.

Comment: @tripleee could you explain how?

Comment: @coder it will match this line `THIS IS NOT A PHONE NUMBER: 000-000-0000`

Comment: @Locke That requires `grep -E` though a somewhat similar syntax is available in plain POSIX `grep`; `\{N\}`

Comment: Your use of the `-w` flag excludes matches which start or end in the middle of a "word" token, but does not exclude matching on strings which contain additional information. `grep -x` would require the match to fill the entire input line.